# Update parent entity when updating children on cascade

Tags: typeorm

I am looking for a way to update parents entities when updating children entity using cascade on a OneToMany relationship.

#### Entities

```js
@Entity()
export class Activity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Date;

    @OneToMany(
        type => ActivityTranslation,
        activity_translation => activity_translation.activity,
        {
            cascade: true
        }
    )
    activity_translations: ActivityTranslation[]

}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class ActivityTranslation {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Date;

    @ManyToOne(
        type => Activity,
        activity => activity.activity_translations,
        {
            onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
        }
    )
    activity: Activity

}
```

#### Repository

```js
    public async updateActivityTranslation(activity_translation: ActivityTranslationModel): Promise<ActivityTranslationModel> {
        try {
            delete activity_translation.updatedAt;
            return this.repository.save(activity_translation);
        } catch {
            throw new ServerError("Unable to update activity translation")
        }
    }
```

#### Controller

```js
        await this.activityTranslationRepository.updateActivityTranslation(activity_translations[i]);
```

The activity_translation is updated as expected.
I would like to update the updatedAt column of activity entity when saving activity_translation entity.

I tried everything I found about cascade issues on GitHub and StackOverflow.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Table triggers directly at the database level

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not a solution.... but i was able to do it by forcing the parent entity to change by updating one field. For example, create a field being the number of elements related and update it in the updating method.